# Nativescript: Cannot overwrite ActionBar in template

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am currently learning Nativescript and want to implement a sample Android app with Angular2.

When I route to a component that shall overwrite the default visible startpage `ActionBar` in the template with custom title and  navigation button, nothing happens.

My Component with custom ActionBar:

```js
@Component({
  template: `
  <ActionBar title="CustomTitle">
    <NavigationButton text="Back" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back"></NavigationButton>
  </ActionBar>

   <StackLayout>
        <Label text="Hello World" textWrap="true"></Label>
        <page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>
    </StackLayout>
  `
})
export class TestComponent {}
```

The title can only changed programmatically by `page.actionBar.title = "MyGoals"`, but i dont want that in this case.

I tried to lean on [Nativescript ActionBar Doc](http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/ui/action-bar.html#showinghiding-the-actionbar)  and [Sample Groceries](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries/tree/master/app) which seem to implement it similarly.

What must be done differently to change ActionBar in the template for a Android app?

---

**Update**

When i take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40260112/5669456) code and separate TestComponent in a feature module, the action bar does not work anymore for TestComponent - it shows the default title.

```js
// main.ts
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic, NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { NgModule, Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

@Component({
    template: `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent { }

@Component({
    template: `
        <ActionBar title="Home"></ActionBar>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label text="Home component" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Button text="test" [nsRouterLink]="['/test']"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    `
})
export class HomeComponent { }

@Component({
    template: `
        <ActionBar title="Test"></ActionBar>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label text="Test component" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Button text="home" [nsRouterLink]="['/']"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    `
})
export class TestComponent { }


const testRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "test",
        component: TestComponent
    }
]

@NgModule({
    declarations: [TestComponent],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild(testRoutes)
    ],
})
class TestComponentModule { }


const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        pathMatch: "full",
        component: HomeComponent
    }
]

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent, HomeComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        TestComponentModule
    ],
})
class AppComponentModule { }

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppComponentModule);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there!
Your configuration seems to be working. Although, the `<page-router-outlet>` tag doesn't make sense in the `TestComponent`. Here is a simple nativescript-angular app which correctly updates the actionbar:

```js
// main.ts
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic, NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { NgModule, Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes } from "@angular/router";
import { NativeScriptRouterModule } from "nativescript-angular/router";

@Component({
    template: `<page-router-outlet></page-router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent { }

@Component({
    template: `
        <ActionBar title="Home"></ActionBar>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label text="Home component" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Button text="test" [nsRouterLink]="['/test']"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    `
})
export class HomeComponent { }

@Component({
    template: `
        <ActionBar title="Test"></ActionBar>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label text="Test component" textWrap="true"></Label>
            <Button text="home" [nsRouterLink]="['/']"></Button>
        </StackLayout>
    `
})
export class TestComponent {}

const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: "",
        pathMatch: "full",
        component: HomeComponent
    },
    {
        path: "test",
        component: TestComponent
    }
]

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ AppComponent, HomeComponent, TestComponent ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule.forRoot(routes)
    ],
})
class AppComponentModule {}

platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppComponentModule);
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed example, your app works for me, too.  I update my question with a slightly adjust version of your code. If I separate TestComponent in a feature module, the ActionBar does not work anymore...

Comment: You should import the `NativescriptModule` to your new feature module :).

Comment: that did the trick :). I had to set NativeScriptModule and NativeScriptRouterModule in every feature module.

Comment: You may also add a `SharedModule` that exports all your common (shared) modules, directives, components, etc. Then you can import only the `SharedModule` in all your feature modules. Check the [NG2 Docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#shared-module) for an example.

Comment: `NativeScriptRouterModule.forChild` when creating your pages as shared modules, nativescript doesn't seem to find them